# Applying a particular rule to a held (or unevaluated) function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a very novice Mathematica user and still can't get my head around its evaluation control, all possible constructs related to it (e.g. `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, etc.) and how they work, despite the thorough documentation and the numerous StackExchange and StackOverflow questions discussing this topic. So, apologies for any possible duplicates.

My use case is the following: I have a function (say `f`) defined by thousands of rules and patterns (`DownValues`). I want to start from an unrolled representation of `f[expr]` (for some `expr`) and get the result of applying a single, particular rule to `f[expr]`. I want the result to stay unrolled as well.

As a particular example, suppose we have the following:

```
 In[1]: nat[0] := 0
 In[2]: nat[n_] := 1 + nat[n - 1]
 In[3]: DownValues[nat]
Out[3]: {HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]}
 In[4]: nat[10]
Out[4]: 10
```

Now, I want to start from an expression represented as `nat[10]` (unevaluated!) and want to specifically apply the second rule (`HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]`) to obtain the expression in the form of `1 + nat[9]`. Analogously, shall I wish to apply the first rule (`HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0`), I would expect the result to stay unchanged in its original form, i.e. `nat[10]`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question was also asked in Mathematica's StackExchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242527/applying-a-particular-rule-to-a-held-or-unevaluated-function/243825).

Answer (score 0):

This should help with your understanding of Mathematica's method of operation.

Wolfram reference : [The Ordering of Definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#26982)

I.e. Mathematica "looks for the value of an expression of the form f[*n*], it tries the special case f[1] first, and only if this does not apply, it tries the general case f[n_]."

So with the functions below `nat[0]` is always tried first, but of course it only evaluates if the argument is 0.  Then `nat[n_]` is tried.

```
nat[0] := 0
nat[n_] := 1 + nat[n - 1]
```

For your question as to obtaining `1 + nat[9]` here is one way

```
Clear[nat]

nat[0] := 0
nat[n_] := HoldForm[1 + nat[o]] /. o -> n - 1

ans = nat[10]
```

> 1 + nat[9]

```
Do[ans = ReleaseHold[ans], 10]

ans
```

> 10

Alternatively (and better)

```
Clear[nat]

nat[0] := 0
nat[n_] := With[{m = n - 1}, HoldForm[1 + nat[m]]]

ans = nat[10]
```

> 1 + nat[9]

```
Do[ans = ReleaseHold[ans], 9]

ans
```

> 9 + (1 + nat[0])

Note this is the result after 10 iterations. The final `ReleaseHold` results in `nat[0]` evaluating to 0.

```
ReleaseHold[ans]
```

> 10

You might find it easier to see what is happening if you use `Hold` instead of `HoldForm` in the above demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

As posted as a [reply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/243825/78096) in a [parallel discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242527/applying-a-particular-rule-to-a-held-or-unevaluated-function/243825) in Mathematica's StackExchange, I found a relatively more direct and straightforward way of dealing with the problem:

```
 In[6] rules = DownValues[nat]                                                 
Out[6] {HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]}

 In[7] DownValues[nat] = {}                                                    
Out[7] {}

 In[8] nat[10]                                                                 
Out[8] nat[10]

 In[9] nat[10] /. rules[[1]]                                                   
Out[9] nat[10]

 In[10] nat[10] /. rules[[2]]                                                  
Out[10] 1 + nat[9]
```

Comment: `nat[10] /. rules[[1]]` is not actually doing anything with rule 1. Rule 1 only operates on `nat[0]`.  All you are seeing is the input delivered as output, with no replacement.  Also, if you still have definitions for `nat` then `nat[10]` evaluates to 10 before any replacement is attempted.  Mathematica has a system for evaluating shadowed functions, as I mentioned in my answer.  The choice of which rule is used follows this system.